# Scale sideways subfigure to fit to page

Tags: subfloats, scaling, rotating

I have a document with subfigures that are printed sideways with rotating.  I need to scale that figure (with subfigures) to fit to page.

```
%% LyX 1.6.7 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% A simple dot to overcome graphicx limitations
\newcommand{\lyxdot}{.}


\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}

\captcont{Gene Ontology analysis of cancer marked control overexpressed
genes}

\subfigure{ 

\label{fig:cncrUniqMrkdCntrlOvrExp} 

\includegraphics[width=1\\linewidth,height=12cm]{\lyxdot \lyxdot /\lyxdot \lyxdot /fig/go_gprof/go_cncrUniqMrkdCntrlOvrExp}

}

\captcont{Gene Ontology analysis of cancer marked cancer overexpressed
genes}

\subfigure{ 

\label{fig:go_cncrUniqMrkdCncrOvrExp} 

\includegraphics[width=1\\linewidth,height=12cm]{\lyxdot \lyxdot /\lyxdot \lyxdot /fig/go_gprof/go_cncrUniqMrkdCncrOvrExp}

} 

\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

What variables should I use for width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figures begin used are probably long without rotating them, that is why rotating is used.  Thus the width of the figures is what we what to control and we want the width to be equal to the height of the page (because we are rotating).

```
\includegraphics[width=\textheight]
```